# ¿Encontrar un registro comprendido entre dos rangos en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, querybuilder

Hola a todos de ante mano, muchas gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios, quiero lograr lo siguiente, estoy intentando buscar un registro de acuerdo a dos campos en mi base de datos, la estructura de mi tabla con nombre "incident_days" es la siguiente:

```
---+----------------------------+---------------+-------------------+
|id|cat_employee_incident_type_id|first_year_rank| second_year_rank |
---+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
| 1|           2                 |        1      |        5         |
_________________________________+_______________+__________________+
```

En mi controlador tengo la función validateIncidentDates en ella tengo una variable llamada $antiquity, con ella quiero filtrar los registros entre los campos first_year_rank y second_year_rank, estoy intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
public function validateIncidentDates (Request $request) {
    try {
        $antiquity = 3;

        $days_granted  = DB::table('incident_days')->where('cat_employee_incident_type_id', $request->incident_id)
        ->where($antiquity)->between('first_year_rank', 'and', 'second_year_rank')->first();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Error'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Es decir, quiero encontrar los registros donde antiquity se encuentre entre first_year_rank y second_yaear_rank, la tabla tiene más registros, he colocado solo uno para hacer más sencilla la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la busqueda entre fechas se realiza asi:

```
$query->whereBetween('columna', ['fecha_inicio', 'fecha_termino']);
```

Pero veo en tu caso que quieres hacer una busqueda entre 2 columnas
en ese caso debes hacer un filtro por la primera columna, despues por la segunda y recién allí filtrar por antiquity

ejemplo:

```
DB::table('incident_days')->where('cat_employee_incident_type_id', $request->incident_id)
        ->where('first_year_rank','<',$antiquity)
        ->where('second_year_rank','>',$antiquity)->first();
```